# Displaying fragments side-by-side

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to develop an Android application for a tablet in landscape mode with 2 fragments:

1. Fragment 1 contains a list of buttons.
2. Fragment 2 is a space for one the button-related fragments.

With "button-related fragments" I mean the following: When the user presses a button in fragment 1, a fragment associated with that button should be displayed in fragment 2.

Fragment 1 is kind of navigation panel.

In order to implement this, I wrote following code:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="mypackage.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".impl.activities.IntroActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".impl.activities.SimulationActivity"></activity>

</application>
```

`MainActivity` looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements IMainActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(final Bundle aSavedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(aSavedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }

  @Override
  public void show(final View aView, final Class<? extends Activity> aActivityClass) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, aActivityClass));
  }


}
```

`main.xml` has following content:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:name="mypackage.fragments.ContentFragment"/>
```

`ContentFragment` looks like this:

```
public class ContentFragment extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainfrag, container, false);

    IMainActivity mainActivity = (IMainActivity) this.getActivity();
    final IntroButtonClickListener introListener = new IntroButtonClickListener(
        mainActivity, IntroActivity.class);

    final IntroButtonClickListener simulationListener = new IntroButtonClickListener(
        mainActivity, SimulationActivity.class);


    view.findViewById(R.id.intro_button).setOnClickListener(introListener);
    view.findViewById(R.id.simulation_button).setOnClickListener(simulationListener);

    return view;
  }
```

`IntroButtonClickListener`:

```
  class IntroButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
  private IMainActivity mainActivity;
  private Class<? extends Activity> activityClass;

  public IntroButtonClickListener(final IMainActivity aMainActivity,
      final Class<? extends Activity> aActivityClass) {
    this.mainActivity = aMainActivity;
    this.activityClass = aActivityClass;
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(final View aView) {
    this.mainActivity.show(aView, this.activityClass);
  }

}
```

`mainfrag.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="25"
    android:id="@+id/intro_button"
    android:text="@string/intro_button"/>

  <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="25"
    android:id="@+id/simulation_button"
    android:text="@string/simulation_button"/>

  <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="25"
    android:id="@+id/statistics_button"
    android:text="@string/statistics_button"/>

  <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="25"
    android:id="@+id/help_button"
    android:text="@string/help_button"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

This code leads to following results:

1. When I launch the application, there are 4 buttons on the screen (from `mainfrag.xml`).
2. When I press `intro_button` or `simulation_button`, the view changes to `IntroFragment` or `SimulationFragment`, respectively.
3. When I press the Back button, the four buttons are visible again.

My problem: When `IntroFragment` or `SimulationFragment` get visible, the button panel disappears.

How should I modify my code such that *both* button panel *and* the respective "detail" view (`IntroFragment`, `SimulationFragment`) are visible at the same time (there is enough screen space for this) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of example is shown in the APIDemos which are there in the Android SDK. where they have the left panel as listview and the selected item shows the related fragment in right side.

You can find that in

> SDK\android-sdk_r11-windows\android-sdk-windows\samples\android-14\ApiDemos